# Access an Angular scope variable outside of Angular

Tags: angularjs

I need help please, and thank you in advance: I have two Javascript files A.js and B.js. A is written in Angular and B is not. Now B needs to change a value of a scope variable inside A's controller. How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide some code. Without looking at your code, it is difficult to tell.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular in the project already and the angular library is available, you can access the scope assosiated with any particular DOM element using `angular.element().scope()`

So, determine which DOM element is associated with the scope that you need, then use something like `angular.element(document.getElementById('elementId')).scope()`. From that you can access the scope variables.

Be warned though, if you change a variable this way and want the changes to be seen by your angular app, you'd probably need to add a watcher.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, in your **A.js** :

```
window.myVar= $scope.angularVariable;
```

Comment: How do I $watch this window variable inside my Angular controller? Thanks.

Comment: @TellyIpock For that you will need to assign it to a $scope variable and watch it.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. Could you share sample code? Thank you.